# В Redux store - в state, за-push данные, при use(F5) - они сбрасываются, как их сохранить?

Tags: redux

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся с ситуацией когда на сайте добавляются виджеты с информацией, информация приходит с API и сохраняется объектами в стейте редакса. При обновлении страницы она сбрасывается... как сделать так чтобы при обновлении она НЕ сбрасывалась?

```
    componentDidMount() {
    const toRunWeatherInfo = this.props.weatherInfo;
    const propsState = this.props.weatherData;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      const {
        coords: { latitude, longitude }
      } = position;

      const run = () => propsState.length > 0? null : toRunWeatherInfo(latitude, longitude);
      run();

    });
  }
```

Следующая провера почему то не работает и при обновление страницы рисуется 1 виджет даже если их было более одного

Comment: Куда-нибудь их сохранять. Например в localStorage

Comment: Возможно нужно использовать какие то методы реакта? Я пробовал в componentDidMount сделать проверку, на то что : есть ли в моём стейте что либо (this.props.state.length > 0? null : вызов апи получить первые данные) Но после этого получаю ошибку в браузере что props не найдены...